# Kext does not work in macOS 10.12.6 (16G1114)

Tags: macos, iokit, kernel-extension

I followed the tutorial [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptIOKit/iokit_tutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002366-SW6)

I can see my kext by command: `sudo kextload /tmp/MyDriver.kext && kextstat | grep My`

console:

`144    0 0xffffff7f832af000 0x2000     0x2000     com.MyCompany.driver.MyDriver (1) 54793E2C-195A-3CE9-9655-9F68562401BF <4 3>`

But I cannot find any log either in `/var/log/system.log` or `log stream --predicate 'eventMessage contains "My"'`

I tried to trigger a `panic`.

```
volatile char *kernel_panic = NULL;
volatile char message = *kernel_panic;
```

And of course, nothing happens :|

Maybe some useful info:

`csrutil status` : `System Integrity Protection status: disabled.`

After a few minute, my kext disappear from `kextstat` (what :O)

`kextutil -nt /tmp/MyDriver.kext`

```
Code Signing Failure: code signature is invalid
/tmp/MyDriver.kext appears to be loadable (including linkage for on-disk libraries).
```

**EDIT**

Source code is copied from [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptIOKit/iokit_tutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002366-SW6)

Info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.MyCompany.driver.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>KEXT</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
    <dict>
        <key>MyDriver</key>
        <dict>
            <key>IOProviderClass</key>
            <string>IOResources</string>
            <key>IOMatchCategory</key>
            <string>com_MyCompany_driver_MyDriver</string>
            <key>IOKitDebug</key>
            <integer>65535</integer>
            <key>IOClass</key>
            <string>com_MyCompany_driver_MyDriver</string>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.MyCompany.driver.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright © 2018 bu9. All rights reserved.</string>
    <key>OSBundleLibraries</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.iokit</key>
        <string>16.7</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.libkern</key>
        <string>16.7</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

MyDriver.hpp

```
/* add your code here */

#include <IOKit/IOService.h>
class com_MyCompany_driver_MyDriver : public IOService
{
    OSDeclareDefaultStructors(com_MyCompany_driver_MyDriver)
public:
    virtual bool init(OSDictionary *dictionary = 0) override;
    virtual void free(void) override;
    virtual IOService *probe(IOService *provider, SInt32 *score) override;
    virtual bool start(IOService *provider) override;
    virtual void stop(IOService *provider) override;
};
```

MyDriver.cpp

```
/* add your code here */
#include <IOKit/IOLib.h>
#include "MyDriver.hpp"

// This required macro defines the class's constructors, destructors,
// and several other methods I/O Kit requires.
OSDefineMetaClassAndStructors(com_MyCompany_driver_MyDriver, IOService)

// Define the driver's superclass.
#define super IOService

bool com_MyCompany_driver_MyDriver::init(OSDictionary *dict)
{
    bool result = super::init(dict);
    IOLog("MyDriver::Initializing\n");
    return result;
}

void com_MyCompany_driver_MyDriver::free(void)
{
    IOLog("MyDriver::Freeing\n");
    super::free();
}

IOService *com_MyCompany_driver_MyDriver::probe(IOService *provider,
                                                SInt32 *score)
{
    IOService *result = super::probe(provider, score);
    IOLog("MyDriver::Probing\n");
    return result;
}

bool com_MyCompany_driver_MyDriver::start(IOService *provider)
{
    bool result = super::start(provider);
    IOLog("MyDriver::Starting\n");
    volatile char *kernel_panic = NULL;
volatile char message = *kernel_panic;
    return result;
}

void com_MyCompany_driver_MyDriver::stop(IOService *provider)
{
    IOLog("MyDriver::Stopping\n");
    super::stop(provider);
}
```

p/s: apple contains a lot of unused or old info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're making an IOKit kext. IOKit kexts are automatically unloaded by the system if no class instances from that kext are live. So that explains the unloading.

The reasons why there are no instances are either:

- Whatever IOKitPersonalities you were expecting to appear have not appeared, because they didn't match anything, or because your matching dictionary is not valid. What's your IOKitPersonalities dictionary from Info.plist?
- Creating the instance failed. This can be because the class is incomplete (your class is accidentally abstract or you haven't got the correct OSMetaClass boilerplate), or because something along the `init`-`probe`-`attach`-`start` sequence is returning an error.

The code signing failure is not a problem if SIP is disabled, and indeed your kext would not show in `kextstat` if lack of correct signature was preventing it from loading.

You will need to post more code if you would like some more specific help.

Comment: THANK YOU, you saved my life, my IOKitPersonalities is empty. BTW, I'm trying to port a HID USB driver from windows to macOS, am I going the right way ? please

Comment: Depends on the type of device. If you need it to act as the system keyboard or system mouse, then yes, this is probably the correct approach. For other kinds, a userspace driver may be more appropriate. (Note that Apple is planning to remove kext support at some point; I don't know when this will be.)

Comment: It still does not work. Please see my edit, please. Thank you very much

Comment: I'm sorry, but you mentioned "userspace driver". My context is: I have a MCU board and its driver already worked in windows. Now I need to port it to macOS. It look like a HID USB driver. Is it possible if: "userspace driver" not "KEXT" ?

Comment: @LongLT Again, it depends what you need the HID events to do. If the HID events should move the mouse cursor on the macOS desktop, or if they should act like normal system keyboard keypress events, then you may need a kernel driver. If you are trying to control your own Mac application, you can probably just use the IOHID API from the application and don't need a kext. (If this part is still not clear, please create a new question, comments are not meant for asking different questions.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think it's very clearly. Please, do you see any issue with my source ?

Comment: @LongLT The code looks OK, although of course this matches IOResources not a USB device. Also, if you want to produce a panic, use the `panic()` function from the `<kern/debug.h>` header file. The code you wrote has undefined behaviour, so you can't say how it will behave.